# Does a browser reload a page when `back` button is clicked from another domain

Tags: javascript, html5-history

Suppose, a user hits `mydomain.com`. The history stack now contains one entry. Then user clicks a link on my website to `mydomain.com/cool` and I push another state. Now the history stack contains two entries with `mydomain.com/cool` being the last one. Now a user goes to `google.com` - what happens to the history stack?

Does `google.com` is put by browser on top of my two entries? Is history stack tab specific?

And when the user presses back button, will the browser send request to the server to `mydomain.com/cool` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now a user goes to google.com - what happens to the history stack?
>   
> Does google.com is put by browser on top of my two entries?

Yes, the history stack contains now `google.com`, `mydomain.com/cool` and `mydomain.com` in this order.

> Is history stack tab specific?

It is tab specific. In some browsers (expecially mobile ones, where tabs are often not visible on the top of the screen), History stack is tab specific until you reach the "entry point" of the current tab. So if from `google.com` you open in another tab `google.com/some_external_link`, pressing back you will go magically back to the previous tab.

> And when the user presses back button, will the browser send request to the server to mydomain.com/cool ?

It depends. Maybe the browser could retrieve the page from the cache. This happens expecially when you have a static content (without query parameter such as `?page=2`). But you should test browser behaviour in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The history stack is tab specific. it will contain list of urls in order of visit in that tab